# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Bootstrap Modal - Save Changes Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The "Save Changes" button on a Modal is firing the Html.BeginForm() Submit Action Method...

I only want the dedicated "Save Button" which is at the end of the Form to fire it. I want the Save Changes button to call a different action method and save an image which the user has uploaded.

Any idea how I can do this and stop the Save Changes in firing the same action as the Submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly mention which action method should be executed when the form gets posted, by using the appropriate overload of [BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper method.

The below sample will post the form to an action method called `Upload`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                             new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Make sure you have the  HttpPost `Upload` action method in your (home) controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //Uploaded file is in file parmeter.
    //Save and redirect as you wish.
}
```

Comment: Can you change the ActionResult's name to Upload for clarity?